# background task is not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, background, uibackgroundtask

I am trying to execute my code whenever my app enters into background. But my code is not working. Here is my following code:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
__block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask;
NSLog(@"enter in background task");
UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
NSLog(@"app is %@",app);
bgTask = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
    NSLog(@"called function");
    [app endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
    bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
}]; }
```

But my code is not working. As it does not print `called function`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you enabled background tasks for app?

Comment: You have the log statement in the expiration handler. The code in the expiration handler is **not** your background task. It is the code that is called when your background execution time is up. The code you want to execute in the background should follow the call to `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler`. Since you presumably have no code then your app exits the background task and the expiration handler is never called.

Comment: @JohnTracid Yes I have enabled the background tasks. But still it is not working.

Comment: @Paulw11 My app is in background state. But still it is not working

Comment: But what code are you actually trying to run in the background. ?

Comment: I am trying to sync my local data with server. The log `called function` not get printed which I have written under function.